# system of linear equations in a basic model

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider an farm where only wheat and cow (meat) is produced. For the
sake of simplicity we will measure the amount of wheat and cow (meat)
produced in tons (T). In order to produce w T of wheat one requires
w/4 tons of wheat (to be used as seed), w/10 T of cow (which yields the
required amount of cow manure to be used as fertilizer) and w/5 hrs of
labor. Production c T of cow requires 2c T of wheat (to feed the animals),
c/2 T of cow (to breed), and 4c hrs of labor. For workers to provide l hrs
of labor the require l/4 T of wheat and l/10 T of cow. After using some
of wheat and meat produced for wheat, meat production and feeding the
labor, the farmer would like to save 10 T of wheat and 4 T of meat for his
private consumption.

Model the production process of the farm using a system of linear equa-
tions in the variables w (denoting the quantity of wheat), c (denoting the
quantity of cow), and l (denoting the quantity of labor). Does the sys-
tem of linear equations have a solution (where all the variables takes a
non-negative value)?

Comment: What are your own thoughts? Also, the last part *"After using some of wheat and meat produced for wheat, meat production and feeding the labor, the farmer would like to save 10 T of wheat and 4 T of meat for his private consumption"* doesn't make much sense, since "some" isn't well defined.

Comment: i constructed some equations which are not linear and first degree. since i know the question has to be solved by linear equations, i could not make it. And the "some" part, i directly copied and pasted. but it also does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remarked in the comments to your question, that last part isn't well defined, so I'll ignore it for now.

Your equations are 
\begin{align}
-w=&\frac{1}{4}w+\frac{1}{10}c +\frac{1}{5}l\\
-c=&2w+\frac{1}{2}c+4l\\
-l=&\frac{1}{4}w+\frac{1}{10}c
\end{align}

We rewrite these to give zero on the LHS and write them in the basis $\{w,c,l\}$:
$$\mathbf{0}= \pmatrix{\frac{5}{4} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{5} \\ 2 & \frac{3}{2} & 4 \\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{10} & 1}$$

Can you solve it from here?

EDIT: I had forgotten the minus signs. To understand why, multiply by $-1$ on both sides of all equations and interpret it as: "To make one of this thing (plus) I need to use (minus) some of the others."

Comment: yes, i can solve it. but what about savings of farmer? how can we integrate them to these equations?

Comment: @F.Clark I've got no idea - as I said, it isn't well-defined. Try to think of some way to define precisely (and mathematically) what this means and then see how to best incorporate it into the math, play around with a bit.

Comment: i'll try. thank you for all

Comment: @F.Clark No problem, happy to help! As you're new, I'll just let you know: You can show your appreciation of an answer by upvoting it (you probably cannot do this yet, since it requires 15 reputation to do so) and/or "accepting" it as an answer to your question (it's the tick right under the up/down-vote arrows) - you of course don't have to do this with my answer, although I certainly wouldn't mind it :) Cheers!